Case listagg with count distinct
I want need the following query to work:
select tbl.depno
,  case
                 when count(distinct ntl.number) over(partition by tbl.id) > 1 
                 then listagg(ntl.number, ',') within group (order by ntl.number) 
              
                 else 'test'
                end as multiple_number

from table tbl,
notable ntl
where tbl.id = ntl.id
group by tbl.depno

It works when it's like this:
select tbl.depno
, listagg(ntl.number, ',') within group (order by ntl.number)

from table tbl,
notable ntl
where tbl.id = ntl.id
group by tbl.depno

But I need it to work in my case when there's actually more numbers, to then aggregrate and if there is only one, then it must insert a text (for now, test)
So the error message i get when i run the first part is:
ORA--00979: not a GROUP BY expression


Are you sure you should have partition by tbl.id rather than partition by tbl.depno? What would you expect to happen if a depno had multiple id values, but each of those appeared once (or some once, some more than once)? (Also maybe you actually just want listagg(distinct ntl.number) ..., if you're on a recent version that supports that? Depends what 'test' will really be.)

You are aggregating by tbl.depno so all the columns in the SELECT clause should either be tbl.depno or wrapped in an aggregation function.
count(distinct ntl.number) over(partition by tbl.id) is an analytic function (not an aggregation function) and is evaluated for every row and it depends on the ntl.number and tbl.id columns which are neither in the GROUP BY nor wrapped in an aggregation function.
It is unclear what you expected output is but you probably need to aggregate twice using nested sub-queries:
SELECT depno,
       CASE
       WHEN MAX(count_number) > 1
       THEN LISTAGG(numbers, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
       ELSE 'test'
       END AS multiple_number
FROM   (
  SELECT tbl.depno,
         tbl.id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ntl."number") AS count_number,
         LISTAGG(ntl."number", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ntl."number") AS numbers
  FROM   table_name tbl
         INNER JOIN notable ntl
         ON tbl.id = ntl.id
  GROUP BY
         tbl.depno,
         tbl.id
)
GROUP BY
       depno

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (depno, id) AS
SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE notable ("number", id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DEPNO
MULTIPLE_NUMBER




10
1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2


20
test




Or depending on how you want to format the output, maybe:
SELECT depno,
       LISTAGG(multiple_number, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS multiple_number
FROM   (
  SELECT tbl.depno,
         tbl.id,
         CASE
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT ntl."number") > 1
         THEN LISTAGG(ntl."number", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ntl."number")
         ELSE 'test'
         END AS multiple_number
  FROM   table_name tbl
         INNER JOIN notable ntl
         ON tbl.id = ntl.id
  GROUP BY
         tbl.depno,
         tbl.id
)
GROUP BY
       depno

Which outputs a value for each id in the depno:



DEPNO
MULTIPLE_NUMBER




10
1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2


20
test,test



fiddle

Here are two of the options to do it.  Both are based on your first query. Just corrected a bit of your code to get it working.
WITH   --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, DEPNO) AS
        ( Select 101, '10' From Dual Union All
          Select 102, '50' From Dual Union All
          Select 103, '70' From Dual Union All
      Select 104, '90' From Dual
        ),
    notbl (ID, NMBR) AS
        ( Select 101, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 101, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 101, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 9 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 8 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 4 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 5 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 6 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 7 From Dual Union All
      Select 104, 5 From Dual
        )

--    S Q L 1 :
SELECT  DEPNO, Max(MULTI_NMBR) "MULTI_NMBR"
FROM  ( Select      t.DEPNO,
                    Case When Count(Distinct n.NMBR) Over( Partition By t.ID ) > 1
                         Then LISTAGG(Distinct n.NMBR) WITHIN GROUP (Order By n.NMBR) Over( Partition By t.ID )
                    Else 'test'
                    End "MULTI_NMBR"
        From        tbl t
        Inner Join  notbl n ON(n.ID = t.ID)
      )
GROUP BY    DEPNO
ORDER BY    DEPNO

--    S Q L 2 :
Select  Distinct
            t.DEPNO,
            Case When Count(Distinct n.NMBR) Over( Partition By t.ID ) > 1
                 Then LISTAGG(Distinct n.NMBR) WITHIN GROUP (Order By n.NMBR) Over( Partition By t.ID )
            Else 'test'
            End "MULTI_NMBR"
From        tbl t
Inner Join  notbl n ON(n.ID = t.ID)
Order By    t.DEPNO

... both resulting as :
/*
DEPNO  MULTI_NMBR
-----  ----------
10     123
50     789
70     4567
90     test    */

Note: use join syntax instead of deprecated table lists and avoid table/column/object names that are reserved words in Oracle.

Fixed it by changing
then listagg(ntl.number, ',') within group (order by ntl.number) 

to
then listagg(ntl.number, ',') within group (order by ntl.number) over (partition by tbl.id)

